# Pick the last or 8th value from the listed of matched values in RegEx?

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds, regex-greedy, boost-regex

I want to pick the last or 8th value from the list of matched values in RegEx

This is my working [**regex101**](http://regex101.com/r/sQ0kW4/13)

Also I want to know, while executing it on my live JS file, how would I use it? Should I use it as `/.*Version (\S+)/g` or as `(?q).*Version (\S+)` or something else?

Comment: Also I've found that in Drupal, ([0-9\.a-z]+) is working but not (\S+)

Comment: I am still unclear what exactly you're trying to do? Are you wanting to match the last value or pick the last value from the array matches?

Comment: The answer what you've provided me was working well with regex101 and that's the output that I needed `2.4` but the issue is I don't know why now its not working with my Drupal code!

Comment: http://regex101.com/r/sQ0kW4/15

Comment: So your problem is with Drupal, not regex. It seems like @hwnd provided you with the proper regex.